# EF Core Accessing Nested-nested Entity

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, data-access-layer

I have an entity `CallTrackerLog` which has many `Clients` which have a one-many `Advices`. I am trying to HttpPost a create for the `advice`:

```
    [HttpPost("{callTrackerId}/{clientId}/advice")]
    public IActionResult CreateCTClientAdvice(int callTrackerId, int clientId,
        [FromBody] CallTrackerClientAdvice newAdvice)
    {
        if (newAdvice == null)
            return BadRequest();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var ctFromStore = _context.CallTrackers
            .Include(log => log.CallTrackerClients)
                .ThenInclude(log => log.CallTrackerClientAdvice)
            .FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.CallTrackerId == callTrackerId);

        var ctAdviceFromStore ctFromStore.CallTrackerClients.CallTrackerClientAdvice
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CallTrackerClientId == clientId);

        // ... add to db

        return Ok();
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot access the `CallTrackerClientAdvice` with the `.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.CallTrackerClientId == clientId)` - it gives me a red underline even though I thought I loaded it above.

The error:

[image]

How come I am unable to access the `CallTrackerClientAdvice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you want is:

```
var ctAdviceFromStore = ctFromStore.CallTrackerClients
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CallTrackerClientId == clientId)?.CallTrackerClientAdvice;
```